# Como capturar a frequencia do som que esta sendo captado pelo microfone

Tags: c#, áudio

A pergunta é simples, Como determinar a frequência do som obtido pelo microfone em c#? quero construir um afinador de instrumentos para um programa que estou desenvolvendo...

Tem alguma biblioteca pronta? ou então qual o caminho das pedras?...

Comment: Acho que esse link vai te ajudar, já existe alguma coisa pronta.
Link : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/6aabf1a6-fcc8-4841-8137-f6528429fa98/capturar-som?forum=vscsharppt

Aqui já tem o código basicamente Pronto .
Link : https://felipenipo.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/gravando-e-reproduzindo-audios-em-c-net-com-naudio/

Comment: Acho que com esse projeto você consegue interagir com o captador de frequencia https://github.com/naudio/NAudio, mas não vou saber dar um exemplo pra fazer um resposta decente.

Comment: Renan Silveira a minha intenção não é gravar audios, como disse na pergunta quero apenas a frequencia do som que o microfone captura mesmo assim muito obrigado!!, AnthraxisBR eu to tentando com essa biblioteca mais tambem não encontrei nenhum exemplo euiheu' to na briga com ela aqui mais mesmo assim muito obrigado!!

Comment: sei o caminho das pedras, existem diferentes tipos de algoritmos para isso, tudo vai depender do tipo de áudio recebido na entrada do seu microfone, o sinal será monofônico ou polifônico ? existem algoritmos distintos para determinados sinais, até a data de hoje a captura EXATA do pitch/frequência é um problema complexo, se sua pergunta for reaberta eu tentarei colocar as equações que utilizo para capturar frequências ....